# Can Gradequick Web run in ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

I am trying to run this grade book in Ubuntu 12.10, but cannot find a way to make it compatible. I have checked the web for answers, but cannot find a solution, and there does not seem to be any information in the askubuntu database. Can anyone tell me if they have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

GradeQuick now has a web interface available.  I used the Chrome UA Spoofer extension to spoof Safari.  When I went to my Edline page, I was able to open up their web interface called "My Gradebooks".  So there is now a solution for Linux!